# Confused about ref keyword usage in closures

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand how `&` and `ref` correspond. Here's an example where I thought these were equivalent, but one works and the other doesn't:

```rust
fn main() {
    let t = "
        aoeu
        aoeu
        aoeu
        a";
    let ls = t.lines();

    dbg!(ls.clone().map(|l| &l[..]).collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n")); // works
    dbg!(ls.clone().map(|ref l| l[..]).collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n")); // doesn't work
    dbg!(ls.clone().map(|ref l| &l[..]).collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n")); // works again!
}
```

From the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow/ref.html):

```rust
// A `ref` borrow on the left side of an assignment is equivalent to
// an `&` borrow on the right side.
let ref ref_c1 = c;
let ref_c2 = &c;

println!("ref_c1 equals ref_c2: {}", *ref_c1 == *ref_c2);
```

What would the equivalent to `|l| &l[..]` be with `|ref l|`? How does it correspond to the assignment examples in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the docs page for [`Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html)(The iterator adapter for producing lines from a `str`), we can see that the [item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Lines.html#Item.t) produced by it is:

```
type Item = &'a str;
```

Therefore the following happens when trying to do the "doesn't work" version:

```rust
dbg!(ls.clone().map(|ref l| l[..]).collect::<Vec<&str>>().join("\n"));  # doesn't work
//Can become:
let temp = ls
    .clone()
    .map(|ref l| l[..])
    .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
    .join("\n");
println!("{}", temp);
```

Here we can see a crucial problem. [`l` if of type `&&str` (Which I will explain below)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4bb4f2a11e6046a3d4d408432a5c431) so indexing into it will create a `str`, which is unsized and therefore cannot be outside of a pointer of some sort.

---

Now, onto the real thing you wanted to learn: *What a `ref` pattern does*:

> [When doing pattern matching or destructuring via the let binding, the ref keyword can be used to take references to the fields of a struct/tuple.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow/ref.html)

What this does is the following:

- When we have `let ref x = y`, we take a reference to `y`.
- When pattern matching on something (Like in your closure arguments you showed) we have a slightly different effect: the value under the reference is *moved* into the scope and then taken reference to while exposing a way to take the value under the reference. For example:

  > ```
  > fn foo(ref x: String) {}
  > let y: fn(String) = foo;
  > ```
  >
  > This works because what is essentially being done is this:
  >
  > ```
  > fn foo(x: String) {
  >    let x: &String = &x;
  > }
  > ```

  So what `ref x` does is take ownership of `x` and produce a reference to it.

On the other hand

- When we have `let &x = y` we move a value out of `y`.
- This is the opposite of `ref`, in that we take ownership of the value under `y` if we can. For example:

  > ```
  > let x = 2;
  > let y = &x;
  > let &z = y; //Ok, we're moving a `Copy` type
  > ```
  >
  > This is only ok for copy types though as though this isn't *exactly* the same as `let x = *y` which [would work for owned `Box`es](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6edc3baf54ff0d1ff6710530fb3baee1).